# Toggle a minor mode with a custom key binding

Tags: key-bindings, minor-mode

I'd like to be able to toggle `M-x font-lock-mode` with a custom key binding like <kbd>C-c l</kbd> for example (or any minor mode for that matter).

Can this be done relatively easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following to your init file:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c l") 'font-lock-mode)
```

You can follow the same pattern for any minor mode, because all minor modes are *commands* (meaning they can be bound to key sequences).

Moreover, anything you can invoke via `M-x` is a command and can be bound to a key sequence (and using the key binding is equivalent to calling it via `M-x`).

n.b. Your choice of `C-c l` is a good one, as `C-c` followed by an upper- or lower-case letter is always a key sequence reserved for use by end-users, so it should never conflict with any other keymap.